# FancyBox, items added but breaking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

            if (id) {
                el = $('#' + id);

                if (el.length) {
                    this.title = el.html();
                }
            }
        }
        helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

But it's out of order because I keep getting errors in different spots when I move it around. What's the correct way to write this?

Comment: what is `$(this.element)` as compared to `$(this)`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss : in short words, `$(this.element)` is the way to refer to `$(this)` inside the fancybox function.

Comment: @user1648761 : the reason you get errors is because you are missing the `,` separator between the options `beforeLoad : {}` and `helpers : {}` so **add** the separating comma after the closing bracket of the first option like `beforeLoad : {},` or before `helpers`